# Disable automatic terminal in vscode remote

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, terminal

When I connect vscode to a remote system via SSH it will always open a terminal in vscode on the remote machine. I do not want it to do this and always exit the terminal in vscode as soon as it loads. Is there any way to disable this so that it doesn't start this remote terminal in vscode? I don't want to have it start hidden. I do not want it to start at all.

Answer (score 0):

Following [`vscode-remote-release` issue 3439](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3439), try and set the setting:

```
"remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
```

Then restart VSCode, and see if the terminal is still visible.

Comment: This doesn't work. The terminal still appears. I think that even if it didn't appear that it would still launch and just not be visible but I can't test that since the terminal is appearing, regardless of that setting.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode ver 1.65.2

File->Preferences->Settings
In the Search settings input field:

- Type the word-> terminal

Under Extensions:

- Click-> Remote-SSH
- Uncheck-> Always reveal the SSH login Terminal.

Close all VSCode windows and restart VSCode.
Open the remote SSH location and the integrated terminal should no longer open automatically.